# PIL.Image.alpha_composite - choose the start points

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to "paste" one image with 0 alpha layer to another. For that I use PIL.Image.alpha_composite function. Its docs say, the both images should be the same sizes. But it is definitely not true. This code shows, that I can mix 2 images of different sizes:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image_size = (700, 500)
rect_size = (700, 200)
shape = [(0, 0), rect_size] 

#Create blank image 700x500
im1 = Image.new("RGBA", image_size)

#Create blank image for rectangle drawing 700x200
im2 = Image.new("RGBA", rect_size)

#Draw rectangle on it with the same 700x200 dims
im3 = ImageDraw.Draw(im2) 
im3.rectangle(shape, fill ="#ffff33")

#Composite 2 images of 700x500 and 700x200 sizes
im1.alpha_composite(im2)

im1.show()
```

The result can be so:
[image]

My problem is that I want to put rectangle to the bottom. Is it possible to do somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set im2 size to the image size (700, 500) and draw the rectangle at the bottom of im2. Like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image_size = (700, 500)
rect_size = (700, 500)
# Draw rectangle from first point (x=0,y=300) to the second point (x =700,y=500)
shape = (0,300,700,500)

#Create blank image 700x500
im1 = Image.new("RGBA", image_size)

#Create blank image for rectangle drawing 700x200
im2 = Image.new("RGBA", rect_size)


#Draw rectangle on it with the same 700x200 dims
im3 = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
im3.rectangle(shape, fill ="#ffff33")


#Composite 2 images of 700x500 and 700x200 sizes
im1.alpha_composite(im2)

im1.show()
```

Comment: cause I draw text object inside `rect_size` area and after that I want to put it into my base image. The example with rect is more simple to show here.